# SASS/SCSS mixin to generate css grid classes - need additional 20px gap columns for IE 11

Tags: css, sass, internet-explorer-11, css-grid, scss-mixins

I have the following SCSS mixin which generates CSS classes from `.grid1` to `.grid12`:

```
$columns: 12;
@mixin repeat($character, $n) {
    $c: "";
    @for $i from 1 through $n {
        $c: $c + $character;
    }
    -ms-grid-columns: unquote($c);
}


// classes for defining number of equally sized (sub-)grid columns
@mixin grid-x {
    @for $i from 1 through $columns {
        .grid#{$i} {
            @include repeat(" 1fr", $i);
        }
    }
}

@include grid-x;
```

The generated CSS classes look like this using libsass:

```
.grid1 {
  -ms-grid-columns:  1fr;
}

.grid2 {
  -ms-grid-columns:  1fr 1fr;
}

.grid3 {
  -ms-grid-columns:  1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
...
```

Since IE 11 doesn't support `grid-gap` I want to insert 20px gap columns between columns in the generation.

The expected result would look like this:

```
// nothing changed for .grid1
.grid1 {
  -ms-grid-columns:  1fr;
}

.grid2 {
  -ms-grid-columns:  1fr 20px 1fr;
}

.grid3 {
  -ms-grid-columns:  1fr 20px 1fr 20px 1fr;
}
...
```

Simply adding the `20px` columns in the repeat string leads to an unwanted trailing `20px`:

```
@include repeat(" 1fr 20px", $i);
```

results in

```
.grid1 {
  -ms-grid-columns:  1fr 20px;
}                        ^^^^

.grid2 {
  -ms-grid-columns:  1fr 20px 1fr 20px;
}^                                ^^^^

.grid3 {
  -ms-grid-columns:  1fr 20px 1fr 20px 1fr 20px;
}                                          ^^^^
...
```

### Any ideas how to get the desired result using SCSS mixins?

For easy testing, just paste the mixins on [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include another variable for the gap and do it like this.

```
$columns: 12;
@mixin repeat($character, $gap, $n) {
    $c: "";
    @if ($n != 1) {
      @for $i from 1 through ($n - 1) {
          $c: $c+" "+$character+" "+$gap ;
      }
    }
    $c: $c+" "+$character ;
    -ms-grid-columns: unquote($c);
}


// classes for defining number of equally sized (sub-)grid columns
@mixin grid-x {
    @for $i from 1 through $columns  {
        .grid#{$i} {
            @include repeat("1fr","20px", $i);
        }
    }
}

@include grid-x;
```

This will also give you the initial result if you specify and empty string in the gap:

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by myself using `@if () { } @else { }`:

```
$columns: 12;
@mixin repeat($character, $n) {
    $c: "";
    @for $i from 1 through $n {
      @if ($n == 1 or $i == $n) {
        $c: $c + $character;
      } @else {
        $c: $c + $character + " 20px";
      }  
    }
    -ms-grid-columns: unquote($c);
}


// classes for defining number of equally sized (sub-)grid columns
@mixin grid-x {
    @for $i from 1 through $columns {
        .grid#{$i} {
            @include repeat(" 1fr", $i);
        }
    }
}

@include grid-x;
```